# Input fields goes missing in Sales Order Form when there is error

Tags: magento-1.8, sales-order, adminform, form-validation

I am creating a new order from admin panel i.e **Sales -> Orders -> Create New Order**

After filling the form when i hit submit order it throws error but the input fields in **FORM** which i already have filled goes missing. I want to keep the input data in input fields but the fields values goes missing.

What i tried but is not working:

```
<input id="order-billing_address_prefix" name="order[billing_address][prefix]" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["order[billing_address][prefix]"]); ?>" class=" input-text" type="text"> </td>
```

I also tried the following but all in vain:

```
 <input id="order-billing_address_prefix" name="order[billing_address][prefix]" value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_prefix'); ?>" class=" input-text" type="text"></td>
```

and

```
 <input id="order-billing_address_prefix" name="order[billing_address][prefix]" value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('billing_address_prefix'); ?>" class=" input-text" type="text"></td>
```

Any guide will be helpful!

**Note**: I am new to magento and apologies if question is not explained well enough!

Thanks